# Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. while modifying web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, web-config

I want to change web.config file appsetings values which is located in the server. i have given full permission to that folder still unable to access and edit the web.config file

```
while executing the code its giving error saying - Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' .unable to access file resides in server
```

error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'C:\Hosting\chek\demo.checks.in\wwwroot\web.config'    is denied.

aspx.cs

```
string emailid = txtEmailid.Text.Trim();
Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("kumarSunlightitMailid");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("kumarSunMailid",emailid);
config.Save();

lblNewEmailid.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["kumarSunMailid"] + " is ur new mail id";
```

web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="kumarSunMailid" value="krishna@gmail.com" />
 </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are facing this error because you don't give read/write permissions to
>   user..
>
> check couple of things

1. check wether web.config is readonly.. if so then uncheck that Option
2. Right Click on Web.config -> goto properties -> security and check you User does have read/write permissions. if not then give it read/write permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried this, try adding the Everyone User to that folder, and give him full access.  Next, could try setting the configSource of appsettings so that these are stored in a separate config file:

```
<appSettings configSource="appSettings.config" />
```

And then create a new file in the same folder called appSettings.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appSettings>
   <add key="yourKey" value="yourValue" />
</appSettings>
```

Try adding the Everyone user with full access to both files too.

Otherwise, I'd create a new solution an see if you can recreate this odd behavior there.

Comment: how to write this in web .config file ? u have given 2 appsettings @B Wells

Comment: <appSettings configSource="appSettings.config">
  <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001" />

  <add key="kumar" value="krishna@gmail.com" />
 </appSettings>

is it correct???@B wells

Comment: Two different files - web.config and appsettigs.config.  Web.config has a configSource property for linking to a different file.

Comment: i dont have appsetting.cofig file. should i creat. is there any other permissions i should give something like iis_user permission @B wells

Comment: Yes, you need to create that appsettings.config file.  Definitely give it iis_user and perhaps the Everyone user with full access at first.

Answer (score 0):

Please give permission to the current user to full access the iis project or solution.